# How does one prove that a linear multistep method of order p can recover all polynomials up to and including order p?

Tags: numerical-methods

It is intuitive that all polynomials up to and including order $p$ can be fully recovered i.e. without error, but how can one rigorously prove this?

In the book by Lambert, there is a similar question-

Let $L$ be the linear difference operator associated with a linear multistep method. Show that the method has order $p$ if and only if

$$
L[x^r;h]=0, r=0,1,...p
$$